# Как оптимальнее всего работать с большими таблицами в mysql?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Пусть у меня есть таблица со столбцами `user_id (INT)`, `count(INT)`, `date (DATE)`. Таблица хранит некоторую статистику пользователей по дням. В течение дня к базе данных может быть до 50,000 запросов с инкрементированием столбца `count` у определенного пользователя за текущий день (именно за текущий, за предыдущие дни статистика меняться не может). По моей оценке, в этой таблице за небольшой промежуток времени может скопиться около 200,000 записей.

Вопрос в следующем - с нормальной ли скоростью будет работать такая база данных для обычных `select`, `update`, `insert` запросов? Целесообразно ли отделить "архивную" статистику *(статистику за предыдущие дни, которая не может меняться)* в одну таблицу, а статистику за текущий день *(к которой происходит большое число update запросов в течение дня)* - в другую *(при этом каждый день раз в сутки придется переводить данные из "текущей" таблицы в "архивную")*?

Конечно, удобнее всего будет, если все данные будут хранится в одной таблице, но вопрос в скорости при большом количестве данных.

Comment: размер таблицы на скорость update особо не влияет. влияет то, что именно меняется в записи, не растет ли ее длина при этом. на select влияет то требуется ли ему пробегать всю таблицу и тогда он значительно замедляется при росте таблицы или же он работает по индексам и берет лишь ту часть которая нужна. так же на select и insert может существенно влиять правильность выбора первичного ключа таблицы. в идеале наиболее часто запрашиваемые вместе (или вставляемые подряд) записи должны иметь близкие первичные ключи. все это касается конечно InnoDB

Comment: так же почитайте про партиционирование.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за ответ! Первичный ключ у меня составной: (user_id, date). update-запросы имеют вид `UPDATE table SET count = count + 1 WHERE user_id = 1 AND date = 03-07-2018;`, а запросы выборки имеют вид "выбрать строки, у которых user_id = 1, а дата лежит в диапазоне от 01-07-2018 до 03-07-2018". Влияет ли на скорость таких запросов размер таблицы?

Comment: если user_id всегда в выборке то ключ в общем то оправдан. даже более чем. все записи пользователя лежат боле менее рядом. insert могут притормаживать из за перестройки структуры блоков, потому что InnoDB физически располагает записи на диске в порядке следования первичного ключа, следовательно новые записи будут вставляться рядом  с другими записями того же пользователя, т.е. в разные места таблицы. Но если количество операций чтения гораздо больше чем insert (как обычно и бывает), то пусть так и остается

Comment: @Mike, операций insert очень мало, а вот update - может быть 50 000... Но update, понятное дело, не меняет первичные ключи, значит перестройка таблицы не требуется и со скоростью все будет нормально?

Comment: Думаю да. для указанных запросов она практически идеальна. конечно общий объем таблицы имеет некоторое значение, головкам диска дальше бегать приходиться (если он нк ssd). если с этим будут напряги - партиционирование скажем по месяцу должно помочь

Comment: @Mike, да, почитал уже про партицирование, хорошая штука... Теперь все понятно, спасибо за ваши ответы, как всегда помогли :)